# ¿como saber el id de <a> con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría saber el id de `<a>` ¿como lo podría obtener? con esta "estructura"

```
(href:javascript:mifuncion)
```

¿se puede?

```
<a id="precio1" href="javascript:mifuncion(this.id);">Precio: $100</a>
```

El siguiente código lo vi en otra pregunta aquí en stackoverflow y lo direccioné a mi pregunta.Deseo obtener "precio1".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mifuncion(click_id)
{
  alert(click_id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa sintaxis que expones no me parece la adecuada, pues una etiqueta [**`a`**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) tiene un atributo **`href`** con el fin de:

Que el usuario acceda a recursos propios del sitio web que visita o recursos externos de diversa índole **(*recomiendo leer el enlace provisto para un conocimiento amplio y estructurado de la naturaleza de dicho atributo*).**

Pues por ejemplo si imprimes solamente `this` con la estructurqa actual que tienes obtendrás como salida que te retorna:

> [object Window]

Y si sustituyes esa instrucción por un `console.log();` la salida será aún mas amplia, algo así:

> [object Window] {
> addEventListener: function ............................

Y es seguro que si podrías *alcanzar* a dicha etiqueta y obtener el valor del atributo deseado pero *considero que es un esfuerzo francamente innecesario*

En todo caso si deseas acceder al id de la etiqueta `a` puedes:

- Deja inline el llamado a la función JS de la siguiente forma:

```html
    <a id="precio1" onclick="mifuncion(this.id)">Precio: $100</a>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mifuncion(click_id)
    {
      alert(click_id);
    }
    </script>
```

- O también obtener dentro de un script a la etiqueta por medio de su etiqueta y darle un listener a su evento click para que de esa manera se haga la impresión del valor de uno de sus atributos:

```html
    <a id="precio1">Precio: $100</a>
    
    <script>
      let etiqueta = document.querySelector('a');
      
      etiqueta.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert(etiqueta.id);
      })
    </script>
```

En cualquier escenario que eligas debes indicar en que momento ocurrirá el `alert` de dicho valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Con esta estructura no hay forma? href="javascript:mifuncion(this.id)

Comment: @Abner edité mi respuesta, pero igual te recomiendo esperar otras respuestas

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias